# python pandas "cannot set a row with mismatched columns" error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing an issue while adding a new row to the data set.

Here is the example `DataFrame`.

```
column_names = ['A','B','C']
items = [['a1','b1','c1'],['a2','b2']]
newDF = pd.DataFrame(items,columns=column_names)
print(newDF)
```

output:

```
    A   B     C
0  a1  b1    c1
1  a2  b2  None
```

Since c2 was missing, it was replaced with `None`. This is fine and as expected.

Now if i continue to add similar rows to this existing `DataFrame`, like this:

```
newDF.loc[len(newDF)] = ['a3','b3']
```

I get the error "cannot set a row with mismatched columns".

How can I add this additional row, so that it will automatically take care of missing c3 with `None` or NaN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is `DataFrame.append`:

```
>>> new_row = ['a3', 'b3']
>>> newDF.append(pd.Series(new_row, index=newDF.columns[:len(new_row)]), ignore_index=True)
    A   B     C
0  a1  b1    c1
1  a2  b2  None
2  a3  b3   NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

what about just :

```
>>> print(newDF)
    A   B     C
0  a1  b1    c1
1  a2  b2  None
>>> newDF
    A   B     C
0  a1  b1    c1
1  a2  b2  None
```

Just place new index `2` with new values `a3` & `b3` and last column.

```
>>> newDF.loc['2'] = ['a3','b3', np.nan]
>>> newDF
    A   B     C
0  a1  b1    c1
1  a2  b2  None
2  a3  b3   NaN
```

OR

```
>>> row = ['a3','b3', np.nan]
>>> newDF.loc['2'] = row
>>> newDF
    A   B     C
0  a1  b1    c1
1  a2  b2  None
2  a3  b3   NaN
```

Another way around: appending to Dataframe, the new values across the row for desired columns as we have for `A` & `B` this another column for them row will become `NaN`

```
>>> row
['a3', 'b3']
>>> newDF.append(pd.DataFrame([row],index=['2'],columns=['A', 'B']))
    A   B     C
0  a1  b1    c1
1  a2  b2  None
2  a3  b3   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks.. I didnt want to hardcode the index/column names into the code, hence  following @timgeb approach

Answer (score 3):

You specify your new row as a dictionary and create a dataframe out of it.

```
new_entry = {'A': ['a3'], 'B': ['b3']}
new_entry_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_entry)
```

Now this can be appended to the original dataframe

```
newDF.append(new_entry_df)

    A   B     C
0  a1  b1    c1
1  a2  b2  None
0  a3  b3   NaN
```

Comment: This hardcodes the column names of `newDF` aligned with the items of the new row. Consider `new_entry = dict(zip(newDF.columns, ['a3', 'b3']))`.

Comment: You also need `ignore_index=True` with `newDF.append` because OP wants the new row to have index `2`.

Comment: @timgeb But what if I wanted a3 to be the value of column C and b3 of column B?

Comment: There's the case in which you manually want to specify into which columns the items of the new row should go, in this case the hardcoded keys are a good idea. Then there's the case where the new row should just be padded with NaN in order to fit into the dataframe. I think the latter case is what OP is after.

Comment: Thanks, like @timgeb mentioned, i do not want to hardcode the column names. I am getting random, dynamic data, hence i cannot hardcode column names.