# ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm trying to append the list below to the first row of an empty dataframe.

```
to_append = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

df_length = len(df_b)
df_b.loc[df_length] = to_append
```

The empty dataframe has more columns than the list can be assign to

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
```

When I use the code above I get an error of

```
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

How can I append the list to get a result like this?

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas "cannot set a row with mismatched columns" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569997/python-pandas-cannot-set-a-row-with-mismatched-columns-error)

Answer (score 1):

Setup

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(17))                                                                                       
>>> df                                                                                                                         
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
Index: []
>>> to_append = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Solution

```
>>> df.append([to_append])                                                                                                     
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```